# I want to get the backchannel URI from the ONVIF camera with curl

Tags: curl, onvif, rtsp-client

## What I want to do

The purpose is to be able to input an audio from a microphone on a PC and send and output audio from the audio output terminal of the IP camera.

## Where it's jammed

I want to receive a response like the image below using curl for an ONVIF compatible camera, but the expected response is not returned.
I'm wondering if the DESCRIBE part is written incorrectly, but I haven't found how to fix it.

[ONVIF Core Specification Page 211](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kODMi.png)

## What I tried

```
$ curl -v -X DESCRIBE "rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.212:554/Streaming/Channels/101 RTSP/1.0" -H "Content- Type: application/sdp" -H "User-Agent: ONVIF Rtsp client" -H "Require: www.onvif.org/ver20/backchannel"
*   Trying 192.168.1.212...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.1.212 (192.168.1.212) port 554 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> OPTIONS * RTSP/1.0
> CSeq: 1
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46QW5zdXNlcjA=
> Content-Type: application/sdp
> User-Agent: ONVIF Rtsp client
> Require: www.onvif.org/ver20/backchannel
> 
< RTSP/1.0 200 OK
< CSeq: 1
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Date: Thu, 02 Dec 2021 04:24:30 GMT
< Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, PLAY, PAUSE, GET_PARAMETER, TEARDOWN, SET_PARAMETER
< 
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.212 left intact
```

I would appreciate your guidance.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your camera supports this feature?